# $C^k$ surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and smooth atlas

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

So for an $C^k$ manifold there is a well known result of Whitney's that says that there is a subset of the maximal atlas that makes this manifold $C^\infty$. My concern is that for surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the definition for elements of the atlas is slightly different. Namely the atlas of a $C^k$ surface consists of $C^k$ charts  $\varphi:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$, where $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\varphi_1\times\varphi_2\neq 0$ which satisfy the condition $\varphi_1^-1\circ \varphi_2$ is $C^k$. My question is that do we still have a smooth atlas by taking a subset of the maximal atlas coming from this definition? On a simpler level we could ask if given any point on the surface, can we find a neighborhood diffeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. I appreciate any help or comments you all have. Thanks.

Comment: The equation $\phi_1 \times \phi_2 \ne 0$ does not make much sense. To start with, what are $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$? My guess is that they are two charts $\phi_1 : U_1 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ and $\phi_2 : U_2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$, in which case it makes no sense to take their cross product.

Comment: So basically $\varphi\in C^k$. So it has partial derivatives of order $k$. So you can differentiate them in the vector valued sense. Then take cross products.